# How to visualize condensation test of series convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I visualize cauchy condensation test?I can solve problems using that test.But I could not visualize it properly.I am looking for a suitable diagram that can explain it graphically.I want to know what is going on?

Comment: A diagram will help me a lot.

Comment: The diagrams you're looking for are here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy_Condensation_Test

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Estimate) and the diagram there?

Comment: This diagram helped me a lot and was exactly what I had been finding.